# Sharepoint Designer Installation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have office 365 business essentials subscription and I was trying to install SharePoint designer 2013 on windows10.For some reason I wasn't able to install it after downloading the software. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're an O365 subscriber, you're on SharePoint Online - which does not support SP Designer.  Designer is ok for SP on-prem 2013, not very reliable on 2016, and is a discontinued application.  In Office 365, Flow and PowerApps provide the modern replacement for Designer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  you can use SPD 2013 for 2016 online and it works fine.  I had to download the latest version to use and there was a patch.  [Here is a link](http://This%20is%20not%20true.%20%20you%20can%20use%20SPD%202013%20for%202016%20online%20and%20it%20works%20fine.) to show you how to install it. You will need to make sure you have the August 2016 patch and it will work just fine.

Comment: I'm using SharePoint online 2013 as part of office 365 business essentials subscription. I don't have access to SharePoint 2016 online

Comment: Hi lazoDev, link provided in answer is not working.